# Improve code / remove for-loop when using accumarray MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization, percentile, accumarray

I have the following piece of code that is quite slow to compute the percentiles from a data set ("DATA"), because the input matrices are large ("Data" is approx. 500.000 long with 10080 unique values assigned from "Indices").

Is there a possibility/suggestions to make this piece of code more efficient? For example, could I somehow omit the for-loop?

```
k = 1;
for i = 0:0.5:100; % in 0.5 fractile-steps
     FRACTILE(:,k) = accumarray(Indices,Data,[], @(x) prctile(x,i));
     k = k+1;
end
```

Comment: Just as a note: `accumarray` is a wrapper for a loop anyway.

Comment: Fractile seems to be a matrix, what are you actually trying to do? 
Usually if you want to get rid of a for loop you can try make it a matrix operation, something that matlab is quite good (however bear in mind memory limitations)

Comment: Yes indeed, it is a matrix. I'm storing the individual percentile-results (0:0.5:100) for each of the unique 10080 indices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `prctile` again and again with the same data is causing your performance issues. Call it once for each data set:

```
FRACTILE=cell2mat(accumarray(Indices,Data,[], @(x) {prctile(x,[0:0.5:100])}));
```

Letting `prctile` evaluate your 201 percentiles in one call costs roughly as much computation time as two iterations of your original code. First because `prctile` is faster this way and secondly because `accumarray` is called only once now.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for. Easy to understand and much faster!